# Why we use ~/ before .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I was following a tutorial to setup hadoop single node cluster where to edit bash following pattern is used:
~/.bashrc

Where as in directory the bash file is saved with only ".bashrc".
I am new to linux.

Please view the screenshot of the directory home.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qm3n.jpg

Comment: Please note in the future that we have other StackExchange sites that are probably more suited for such questions (even though you got a quick answer here for this one). In particular, [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~/ is a shortcut to your home directory

If you are already in that directory you don't need it but doesn't hurt

Comment: [Relevant GNU Bash Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
~ = user home directry
. = indicates file/directory is hidden
~/.bashrc is a path
```